# convert mysql to PDO statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This is the login function written using MySQL way
However, the problem exists when it convert into PDO way

MYSQL:

```
    <?
function confirmUser($username, $password){
   global $conn;
   if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $username = addslashes($username);
   }

   /* Verify that user is in database */
   $q = "select UserID,UserPW from user where UserID  = '$username'";
   $result = mysql_query($q,$conn);
   if(!$result || (mysql_numrows($result) < 1)){
      return 1; //Indicates username failure
   }

   /* Retrieve password from result, strip slashes */
   $dbarray = mysql_fetch_array($result);
   $dbarray['UserPW']  = stripslashes($dbarray['UserPW']);
   $password = stripslashes($password);

   /* Validate that password is correct */
   if($password == $dbarray['UserPW']){
      return 0; //Success! Username and password confirmed
   }
   else{
      return 2; //Indicates password failure
   }
}
```

PDO:

```
<?
function confirmUser($username, $password){
   global $conn;

   include("connection/conn.php");

   $sql = '
    SELECT   COALESCE(id,0) is_row
    FROM     user
    WHERE    UserID = ?
    LIMIT 1
';

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array('09185346d'));
$row = $stmt->fetch();

if ($row[0] > 0) {
       $sql = '
    SELECT   COALESCE(id,1) is_row
    FROM     user
    WHERE    UserPW = ?
    LIMIT 1
';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array('asdasdsa'));
$row = $stmt->fetch();
    if ($row[0] > 0) 
    return 2;
    else
    return 0;
}
elseif ($row[0] = 0)
{return 1;}   



}
```

What is the problem ?? And is it necessary to include bind parameter in PDO??? THANKS

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: Error messages? Unexpected behavior? Spontaneous combustion? Give us something to work with here.

Comment: Sorry 
the problem is that it will fall into the return 0 no matter password incorrect or username not exists

Comment: Differentiating between "Username failure" and "Password failure" is bad practice, as it allows people to test for valid usernames before testing for valid passwords. Combine your queries and just have an "Authentication failure". - Also in your code, the password supplied doesn't even have to belong to the correct user, **any** username, and **any** password will allow you to authenticate as long as they are in the database somewhere.

Comment: i found it error when COALESCE(id,0) is_row

Comment: thanks for your idea, i am just too green in web development

Comment: Pass the PDO object in, don't use global.  Global is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from your use of `global` and your `include` inside the function (you should investigate an alternative way of structuring your function not to do this), I would change the code as follows:

```
$sql =
    'SELECT  id
    FROM     user
    WHERE    UserID = ?
    AND      UserPW = ?
    LIMIT 1';

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(
    '09185346d',
    'asdasdsa'
));

if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
    return 0;
}
else {
    return 1;
}
```

Combing the queries to give a general Authentication error, instead of allowing people to trial valid usernames, and then valid passwords, and then using PDOStatements `rowCount` method do see if your row was returned.

To answer your second part, it is not necessary to specifically use `bindParam` to prevent SQL injection.

Here's a quick example of the difference between `bindParam` and `bindValue`

```
$param = 1;

$sql = 'SELECT id FROM myTable WHERE myValue = :param';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
```

Using `bindParam`

```
$stmt->bindParam(':param', $param);
$param = 2;
$stmt->execute();
```

SELECT id FROM myTable WHERE myValue = **'2'**

Using `bindValue`

```
$stmt->bindValue(':param', $param);
$param = 2;
$stmt->execute();
```

SELECT id FROM myTable WHERE myValue = **'1'**

Comment: The whole point of prepared statements is to 1) Speed up repetitive queries by caching the servers query analysis, and 2) separate variable parameters from the body of the query to prevent things like SQL injection. It is not necessary to explicitly use `bindParam` to prevent SQL injection. `bindParam` binds a **reference** to a variable to your prepared query, which is evaluated at the point you call `execute` and is useful when you explicitly want to **typecast** the parameter being bound. `bindValue` is the same, but the bound parameter is evaluated immediately. You don't have to use them.